# python list's remove method has some issues. I have attached the code below. The code does not remove all elements with len less than 3

Tags: python, list, for-loop, nested-lists

python list's remove method has some issues.
I have attached the code below.
The code does not remove all elements with length less than 3

```
result=[['10'], ['5'], ['6'], ['12'], ['9'], ['10'], ['5', '9', '10'], 
['5', '10'], ['13'], ['9', '10'], ['1']]

for i in result:
    if len(i)<=2:
        result.remove(i)
print (result)
```

The result prints as [['5'], ['12'], ['10'], ['5', '9', '10'], ['12']]
Any help is really welcomed and appreciated

Comment: You shouldn't remove items from a list while iterating it. Instead, build a new list with the items you want to keep.

Comment: Deleting from a list while iterating over it is like sawing off the branch you’re sitting on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that you are manipulating the list while iterating over it. You better create a filtered copy of the result list:

```
result=[['10'], ['5'], ['6'], ['12'], ['9'], ['10'], ['5', '9', '10'], ['5', '10'], ['13'], ['9', '10'], ['1']]

filtered_result = []

for i in result:
    if len(i)>2:
        filtered_result.append(i)

print(filtered_result)
```

Or for example using `filter`:

```
result = filter(lambda x: len(x)>2, result)
```

You could also use list comprehension:

```
result = [x for x in result if len(x)>2]
```